# How to externally unbind an event which is created in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, richtextbox

I want to disable copy-paste in Textangular module without touching its code. 
I went though its code and came to know that there is an event binding for "paste" action.

Is it possible to unbind the paste event externally? For example when the controller is loaded or using another directive ?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating another directive and adding it to element on which the event is binded. Then inside link function try to do something like this: `element.off("paste");`. The main concern here will be order of executing directives, but you can try...